# How to migrate from defaultProps to Default Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Loader` component which works as expected with `defaultProps`:

```js
const Loader = ({ inner, outer, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 200 152" {...rest}>
      <path
        fill="none"
        id={inner.id}
        stroke={inner.color}
        d="M99.217 100.606L58.302 29.74h81.829l-40.914 70.866z"
      />
      <path
        fill="none"
        id={outer.id}
        stroke={outer.color}
        d="M100 151L13.398 1h173.205L100 151z"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

Loader.defaultProps = {
  id: 'loader',
  inner: {
    id: 'inner',
    color: 'black'
  },
  outer: {
    id: 'outer',
    color: 'black'
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Loader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I want to migrate it to use [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) while [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a predefined `defaultProps`, but I can't figure it out:

```
const defaultProps = {
  id: 'loader',
  inner: {
    id: 'inner',
    color: 'black'
  },
  outer: {
    id: 'outer',
    color: 'black'
  }
};

// Not working, runtime exception - `id is undefined`
const Loader = ({ inner, outer, ...rest } = defaultProps) => {
  return ...
};

// works, but id is still undefined
const Loader = ({
  inner = defaultProps.inner,
  outer = defaultProps.outer,
  ...rest
}) => { return {...}; }
```

Sandbox with all examples above:

[image: Edit Q-DefaultProps-to-ES6-Defaults]

Comment: Please use **on-site** Stack Snippets for runnable examples rather than off-site resources. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can if you want the outermost `id` to be in `rest` (because you can't define a default for a rest target). But if you accept the outermost `id` as a named destructured parameter, you can do this by specifying the default values within the destructuring in the function signature, and assigning a blank default to the parameter as *its* default:

```
const Loader = ({
         id = 'loader',       //
         inner = {            //
             id: 'inner',     //
             color: 'black'   //
         },                   // Various defaults for the destructuring
         outer = {            //
           id: 'outer',       //
           color: 'black'     //
         },                   //
         ...rest
    } = {}
//   ^^^^^---- default for the parameter itself
) => {
        // ...
};
```

*(Formatting is a real pain, though. :-) )*

Live Example:

```js
const Loader = ({
         id = 'loader',
         inner = {
             id: 'inner',
             color: 'black'
         },
         outer = {
           id: 'outer',
           color: 'black'
         },
         ...rest
    } = {}
) => {
  return (
    <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 200 152" {...rest}>
      <path
        fill="none"
        id={inner.id}
        stroke={inner.color}
        d="M99.217 100.606L58.302 29.74h81.829l-40.914 70.866z"
      />
      <path
        fill="none"
        id={outer.id}
        stroke={outer.color}
        d="M100 151L13.398 1h173.205L100 151z"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Loader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```